# Getting all latest data with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, while-loop

Currently when using ajax I only return 1 result, but once that result has posted it doesn't post anymore new results.

For instance: A user posts on a wall three times and it doesn't insert those three new records into my notifications, it prints one and sits there until the page has been refreshed by the user and shows the other two. How could I adapt my code for it to return all new notifications.

Also if a user has no notifications and they get one, unless I refresh the page it doesn't show the first new notification unless they refresh the page.. and then this is when it starts grabbing new data.

**SERVER SIDE - PHP**

```
$json = array();

$com=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT notification_id,notification_content,notification_targetuser,notification_time,notification_triggeredby,notification_throughurl FROM notifications WHERE notification_targetuser='$user2_id' AND notification_id > '$id' AND notification_status=1 ORDER BY notification_id DESC LIMIT 10");
echo mysqli_error($mysqli);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($com);

if($num && $user2_id){

    $json['num'] = $num;
}else{
    $json['num'] = 0;
}
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($com);
$json['notification_id'] = $resultArr['notification_id'];
$json['notification_content'] = $resultArr['notification_content'];
$json['notification_triggeredby'] = $resultArr['notification_triggeredby'];
$json['notification_targetuser'] = $resultArr['notification_targetuser'];
$json['notification_throughurl'] = $resultArr['notification_throughurl'];
$json['notification_time'] = $resultArr['notification_time'];
mysqli_free_result($com);

echo json_encode($json);

}
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
$user1_id= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']);
$call="select notification_id,notification_status,notification_targetuser from notifications WHERE notification_status=1 ORDER BY notification_id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $chant=mysqli_query($mysqli,$call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));


while($notification=mysqli_fetch_array($chant)){
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var notification_id="<?php echo $notification['notification_id'] ;?>";
        function loadIt() {

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id,   
    dataType:"json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
    if(data.num>0){
     $("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id).prepend('<div class="notif_ui"><div class="notif_text"><img border="1" src="userimages/cropped'+data['notification_triggeredby']+'.jpg" onerror=this.src="userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg" width="40" height="40" ><br /><a href="'+data['notification_throughurl']+'">'+data['notification_content']+' </a><br /><abbr class="timeago" title="'+data['notification_time']+'"> '+data['notification_time']+'</abbr></div></div>');
     i = parseInt($("#mes").text()); $("#mes").text((i+data.num)); 
        }
        if(!data.notification_id.length) {
       //no results...
       return;
    }
    notification_id = data.notification_id; 
    }
    });
    }
    setInterval(loadIt, 10000);              
     </script>
```

Comment: This `if($num && $user2_id)` should most likely need to be `if($num > 0)`

Comment: possibly @Fred-ii- but still doesn't solve my problem. I have checked my console and realized that the ajax isn't firing until I have 1 new notification and refresh the page. Shall I put a document ready function in there for the first call?

Comment: TBH Dave, I don't know. Ajax isn't my strong point in coding, but you can try it.